Can You Paint & Texture Cement Board/Backerboard
During our remodel of our bathroom shower area, we cut out the existing wall tile and some of the textured drywall around the edges. The person doing the new wall tile is going to put new cement board in and tile over that (including all the other steps). However, from the tiling will not go all the way to where the drywall is.
Here's our question:
We can either put in a small strip of drywall in between and then paint and texture that. Or we can put the backerboard all the way to up to where the drywall cuts off, and then paint and texture the backerboard.
Is it okay to paint and texture backerboard? If so, how should we do it? We were thinking of putting drywall mud over it and then painting and texture over the mud. However, we are not sure.
We don't want to extend the tile out to cover it.
See the picture below. The tile will be finished leaving about an inch left to here the drywall is cut


I've done this a few dozen times.
It needs to be done before tile is installed.
First step is to tape and mud (drywall compound) the seam, adding mud to cover about 2 inches beyond where the tile will end. The small pits and bumps of the cement board must be covered. Sand as you would for any drywall that is getting textured.
Texture the walls and paint. The transition from cement board and drywall will be unnoticable.
As a side note. After painting, I apply a waterproofing to the walls that will get tile and edge the tile with an aluminium trim like Schluter Jolly

Fantastic. I really appreciate your help and extra information!

Mud & sand it to make it smooth, and treat it like drywall from that point forward.

Depending on the texture, you might ba able to just tenture the mud, ie., roll the mud on with a paint roller.

Thank you for your help!
